# Monitor resolution not recognized

Tags: release-loki, display, resolution

The external display's max. resolution is 2560 x 1440, but the maximum resolution I can select on the display settings is 2048 x 1152.

What can I do to use the display in its max. resolution?

System: elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki

Display driver: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: to get the max resolution the your output can reach use: `xrandr -q` this return to you the min and the max resolutions

Answer (score 1):

Based on [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47749/cannot-add-new-mode-in-xrandr-for-external-monitor/)
 you can use `gtf height width refresh_rate` and get an new modeline as response and then you can create new mode with the output of the first command `xrandr --newmode modeline`, after that you need to ensure in which output you want to set up the modeline, you can check this with `xrandr -q` after get the response add the newmode to the desired output `xrandr --addmode OUTPUT "MODELINE"` and apply the new modeline `xrandr --output OUTPUT  --mode MODELINE`.

Answer (score 0):

Please open terminal pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute `xrandr -q` to see the connected displays and their current resolution.
Then execute `xrandr --output <monitor_name> --mode <resolution>` to change resolution. For example, `xrandr --output eDP-2-1 --mode 2560x1440`

Comment: There's no 2560x1440 mode in `xrandr` output. Since I posted the issue I've tried all sorts of possible solutions, the closest one I got is 2560x1440 resolution at 30Hz [2560x1440 or 2560x1600 via HDMI](https://www.notebookcheck.net/2560x1440-or-2560x1600-via-HDMI.92840.0.html) which is not acceptable. I think it is my display driver that cannot handle the resolution.